# negative grep with multiple elements

Tags: r, regex

Assuming the following code using grep

```
grepl("XYz|Aba", results$category)
```

How to obtain the negative statement?

I know that this is normally done using caret ^ but I don't seem to find the right syntax

Comment: You can use `!` i.e `!grepl("XYz|Aba", results$category)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative lookahead.

```
grepl("^(?!.*(?:XYz|Aba))", results$category, perl=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can negate it

```
 !grepl("XYz|Aba", results$category)
```

Comment: @SabDeM It will match the characters instead of `XYz` as a group

Comment: @SabDeM I don't think it works as it is character matching